# Select corresponding values to a instant t in columns

Tags: python, pandas

I work in Python and i have a pandas Dataframe with an evolution of steps at differents months :

```
+----+-------+------+
| Id | Month | Step |
+----+-------+------+
| a  |     1 | a_1  |
| a  |     4 | a_2  |
| a  |     6 | a_3  |
| b  |     1 | a_1  |
| b  |     2 | a_4  |
+----+-------+------+
```

I want to have the evolution of steps corresponding to each month in columns like this table :

```
+----+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Id | Month_1 |  Month_2 | Month_3 | Month_4 | Month_5 | Month_6 |
+----+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| a  | a_1     | a_1      | a_1     | a_2     | a_2     | a_3     |
| b  | a_1     | a_4      | a_4     | a_4     | a_4     | a_4     |
+----+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I don't find simple solution, so if someone have a solution, i take !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
new_df=df.pivot_table(index='Id',columns='Month',values='Step',aggfunc=''.join).add_prefix('Month_').rename_axis(columns=None)
print(new_df)
   Month_1 Month_2 Month_4 Month_6
Id                                
a      a_1     NaN     a_2     a_3
b      a_1     a_4     NaN     NaN
```

---

If you want appear all rage of months 
and fill use:

```
new_df=( df.pivot_table(index='Id',columns='Month',values='Step',aggfunc=''.join)
         .reindex(columns=range(df['Month'].min(),df['Month'].max()+1))
         .ffill(axis=1)
         .add_prefix('Month_')
         .rename_axis(columns=None)
         .reset_index())
print(new_df)
  Id Month_1 Month_2 Month_3 Month_4 Month_5 Month_6
0  a     a_1     a_1     a_1     a_2     a_2     a_3
1  b     a_1     a_4     a_4     a_4     a_4     a_4
```

---

If you don't want fill remove `ffill`

Comment: You didn't take the last step :) -`.ffill(1)` before `.add_prefix('Month_')`

Comment: I don't know if OP want ffill. Thanks by suggest:)